# how to convert string json object to json object in bash linux

Tags: json, string, sed, jq

I have below string json in a file as file.json:

```json
"{\n  \"devices\" : [ {\n    \"type\" : \"eks\",\n    \"kubeconfig_path\" : \"/home/centos/workspace/rt-argus-eks-parallel-dynamic-infra/ansible/utils/dynamic-infra-v2/./kubeconfig-jenkins-rt-argus-eks-parallel-dynamic-infra-70_0\"\n  }, {\n    \"type\" : \"eks\",\n    \"kubeconfig_path\" : \"/home/centos/workspace/rt-argus-eks-parallel-dynamic-infra/ansible/utils/dynamic-infra-v2/./kubeconfig-jenkins-rt-argus-eks-parallel-dynamic-infra-70_1\"\n  } ]\n}"
```

I am trying to convert this to something like this:

```json
{
  "devices" : [ {
    "type" : "eks",
    "kubeconfig_path" : "/home/centos/workspace/rt-argus-eks-parallel-dynamic-infra/ansible/utils/dynamic-infra-v2/./kubeconfig-jenkins-rt-argus-eks-parallel-dynamic-infra-70_0"
  }, {
    "type" : "eks",
    "kubeconfig_path" : "/home/centos/workspace/rt-argus-eks-parallel-dynamic-infra/ansible/utils/dynamic-infra-v2/./kubeconfig-jenkins-rt-argus-eks-parallel-dynamic-infra-70_1"
  } ]
}
```

trying to do with

jq -rc file.json

can i do it without jq as well? can i do it with sed also

Comment: To just pretty-print, use `jq . file.json`

Comment: I don't understand what's in file.json. Please add to your question the (properly formatted) output of `cat file.json`

Comment: The desired output is also unclear.  What is the colorization supposed to represent?  Do you want terminal escape characters to manipulate the color in the output?

Comment: If you are asking "can I replace `\n` with an actual newline?" that's easy with Linux `sed`; what's harder is only replacing it when it's not part of another backslash sequence, like `{"\\no \\n here"}`

Comment: Where do you have that string? What do you mean with "convert"? The string already contains JSON. Depending on how and where you are going to use it, you don't need to do anything.

Comment: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Convertto/fromJSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `fromjson`.

```bash
jq fromjson file.json
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/ByKAr9MAcBj) on jqplay